# Freeform recipients not sending to recipient

Tags: templates, forms

Hi I am new to EE and found the FreeForm Module for Contact Forms.
It is pretty Helpful and i love how fast you can create forms with it.
One thing is not working though and as i read other posts about this topic i can not find reasons why it is not working.
Here is the Code

```
{exp:freeform:form
            form_id="1"
            required="first_name|last_name|email|user_message"
            return="{segment_1}"
            recipient1="Topic1|t1@domain.de"
            recipient2="Topic2|t2@domain.de"
            recipient3="Topic3|t3@domain.de"
            recipient4="Topic4|t4@domain.de"
            recipient5="Topic5|t5@domain.de"
            recipient6="Topic6|t6@domain.de"
            recipient_template="user-request"
            notify_user="yes"
            recipients="yes"
            user_email_field="email"
            recipient_limit="8" 
            }
                <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
                <input name="first_name" id="first_name" type="text"/><br/>
                <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
                <input name="last_name" id="last_name" type="text"/><br/>
                <label for="email">E-Mail Address *</label>
                <input name="email" id="email" type="text"/><br/>
                <label for="recipient_email">Subject *</label>
                   <select name="recipient_email">
                {freeform:recipients}
                 <option value="{freeform:recipient_value}" {if freeform:recipient_selected}selected="selected"{/if}>
                    {freeform:recipient_name}
                 </option>
                {/freeform:recipients}
                </select>  <br/>

                <label for="user_message">Your Message *</label>
                <textarea name="user_message" id="user_message"></textarea> <br/>
                <label for="submitForm"></label>
                <input id="submitForm" type="submit" value="Send Form"/>
            {/exp:freeform:form}
```

So it does find errors, and it does send an e-Mail to the admin but it does not send an email to the selected recipient nor the user.

What did i miss to set up correctly? 
( i changed the e-mail adresses in case of spamming :) )

Comment: Just to make sure, are you sure it isn't going to their spam folder?

Comment: It's often helpful to test to make sure EE can actually send email out before diagnosing within Freeform. If you go to Tools -> Communicate and create a message there (to an external email) you'll be able to see if it's an EE or server email configuration issue, or something in Freeform.

Comment: Well the thing is, the Form answers w/ Your email has been sent Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: mail But no E-Mail is received. How can i debug, where the error accures. Is there something? i feel kind of helpless here :-/

Comment: Sounds like this isn't an EE issue but is probably an issue at the server level... I'd suggest contacting the web host directly.

Answer (score 2):

Double check this parameter to make sure the template is named "user-request":

```
recipient_template="user-request"
```

Also, try recoding your select like this:

```
<select name="recipient_email" id="recipient_email">
    <option value="{freeform:recipient_value1}">Option</option>
    <option value="{freeform:recipient_value2}">Option</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the communicate module isn't delivering emails either then try setting up the SMTP option under admin>email.

Also make sure you have set a default email address within EE (can't recall where that's set)

Finally, are the email addresses from the same domain... me@mysite.com & www.mysite.com.

Failing all those, reach out to your host to see if they allow or have available the php mail module. Also check your sites error logs, long shot but you never know.